# How to authenticate user via Kentico 7.x API in ASP.NET webpart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I try to create new documents in kentico via API, but I have a problem with user authentication. I try to use the following code:

```
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(CMSContext.CurrentUser);
```

but my authorisation system on the site is not connected with kentico authoristation and it does not work. I tried also put admin username there:

```
CMS.SiteProvider.UserInfo userInfo =
CMS.SiteProvider.UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo("administrator");
CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeProvider tree = new CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeProvider(userInfo);
```

It also does not work. I found an example to authenticate user in code but it was for Kentico 4.x, now I use kentico 7.x which do not support "AuthenticateUser" method

```
CMS.SiteProvider.UserInfo ui = CMS.SiteProvider.UserInfoProvider.AuthenticateUser(txtboxUsername.Text,
txtboxPassword.Text, CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.CurrentSite.SiteName);
```

Could you suggest me how can I authenticate user in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to you think is an authentication problem? The code you posted just instantiates TreeProvider, it does not create documents. I suggest to look at API examples which you can find under Site manager - Support - API Examples - Documents. Basically it will be something like this:

```
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(CMSContext.CurrentUser);

// Select root at parent
TreeNode parentNode = tree.SelectSingleNode(CMSContext.CurrentSiteName, "/", "en-us");

// Create a new instance of the Tree node
TreeNode newNode = TreeNode.New("CMS.MenuItem", tree);

// Set the document's properties
newNode.DocumentName = "Document name";
newNode.DocumentCulture = "en-us";

// Set document type specific fields
newNode.SetValue("Field1", "value");

// Insert the document into the content tree
DocumentHelper.InsertDocument(newNode, parentNode, tree);
```